# Putting three.js inside of div 2

Tags: three.js

I apologize for one more basic question which basically is a copy of another old thread, but I'm new to three.js and learning more or less through trial and error over here...

I found the old thread 'Putting three.js animation inside of div' where they succeeded putting a three.js animation inside of a div with the following lines of code:

```
container = document.getElementById( 'canvas' );
document.body.appendChild( container );
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( 200, 200 );
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

A JSFiddle of above script (http://jsfiddle.net/fek9ddg5/1/)

I'm trying to do the same and added the lines to my script, but ended up with a completely white screen instead. I managed to basically part the screen in two parts, one completely white and another with the script. However, it failed since the script reacted to the mouse even if it moved in the white part. I made a codepen, I placed the script I added inside of comment-signs.

See it here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qRdGWo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually to add three.js to a page I would use this:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
// Add renderer to page
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Create camera.
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 400;
```

As can be seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pha/ne7gjdnq/)

But, to add it to a div that is already on the page with the ID 'canvas-container' I would use..

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
// get the div that will hold the renderer
var container = document.getElementById('canvas-container');
var w = container.offsetWidth;
var h = container.offsetHeight;
renderer.setSize(w, h);
// add the renderer to the div
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Create camera.
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, w / h, 1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 400;
```

Which can be seen in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pha/ne7gjdnq/90/)

Basically where the renderer is added is determined on what dom element you call `appendChild(renderer.domElement)` on.

Comment: Thank you. The second alternative your described is exactly what I am trying to achieve but the result is always the same, a separate white header with a black box inside... Check out this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qRdGWo

Comment: The first bit of code is just adding the renderer to the body, it's the second that adds it to a div. I posted both so you could see the difference and hopefully understand it.

Comment: The code in the pen you linked to is a mess. You are creating 2 renderers, 1 webGL and 1 Canvas, and adding them both to the canvas-container div

Comment: The black box at the top left is the webglRenderer, which is only 200x200 because it gets it's width and height from the canvas-container div. The stars part at the bottom is the canvasRenderer which is also added to the canvas-container div. Only the canvas div does anything because that is the one you are adding the particles to and the one you are calling the render function on

Comment: [HERE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/egpYEb) is your pen, cleaned up, second(canvas) render removed, events changed to listen on the container div, stats fixed......  You can change the size and position of the three.js scene simply by changing the css on the 'canvas-container'

Comment: I didn't change anything about the SpriteMaterial except remove the reference to the 'program' function which is not correct (as I said in the last question of yours I answered)

Comment: Thank you a LOT :) I sat down for a couple of hours yesterday and looked through your new script, it made more sense. However, when I used it I saw that the particles was once again squares... I solved it by combining your first script with your second script and now everything is perfect.